# DirectoryNotACondaEnvironmentError: The target directory exists, but it is not a conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've installed the Anaconda3 to use the Jupyter. The first time I open the Anaconda, I installed the Jupyter and it shows the message:

[image]

Then I clicked on "Ok" and it installed and opened without problem. But everytime I open the Anaconda, the jupyter is not installed yet, and I click to install and shows the same message, and then it installed and opened without problem.

So, my issue is to install the jupyter everytime I open the Anaconda. I can open the jupyter with the CMD. I've tried to install the jupyter in the environment on CMD, but it shows this message:

```
C:\Users\jp_si>conda activate base

(base) C:\Users\jp_si>conda install jupyter
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: Just to add the cause of this issue - This problem occurs when you have installed anaconda navigator (e.g. for miniconda) previously and did not remove the folder. The solution given by Shubham should work for it.

Answer (score 0):

Open Anaconda Promt as administrator & run this:

conda info --envs

It will show the path of base environment. Copy that Path.

Now, Open Anaconda Navigator from start menu.

Once Anaconda Navigator is opened, press Ctrl + P.

It will open Preferences window for you.

In Preferences Window there is an option "Configure Navigator" click that.

Another window will open with the name of "Navigator Settings (anaconda-navigator.ini)".

In this, a key named "default_env" is there. Paste the Path of base environment by replacing the old one & click on "save and restart".

Now, no need to install Jupyter Notebook & rest of the Applications again & again.

After restarting the Anaconda Navigator, if it again shows "Install" then click it & install. It won't throw any error & won't ask to install again later.